# Can not get shortcode content in function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I use a shortcode on my page like

```
[abc a="b"]test[/abc]
```

In my functions.php

```
add_shortcode('abc', function($atts, $content) {
    return $atts['a']." : ".$content;
});
```

And in my template somewhere

```
<p><?php echo do_shortcode('[abc]') ?></p>
```

$atts, $content are always empty.

Everything works fine in the Default template but not in mine.

I really appreciate if anyone can show me how to get it work in my custom template. Thanks

Comment: you add this shortcode in page content `[abc a="b"]test[/abc]` ?

Comment: I use that in the wp-admin when I add New Page

Comment: ok so how are you fetching the data in custom template page ? please add the full source code of custom page template

Comment: <p><?php echo do_shortcode('[abc]') ?></p> I put that inside HTML of my custom page template, where I want to insert the content of [abc] tag. but the problem is the content is always empty (only with my template, it works fine with the Default template)

Answer (score 0):

You should add these line of code in your custom page template , it will automatically apply filters on content like `wpautop` and other `shortcodes`

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: where in my custom page template should I add that? anywhere or where I put do_shortcode ? Thanks

Comment: just open the custom template php file and put that code in it, it will automatically extract data from shortcodes

Answer (score -1):

I used this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

instead of this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[abc]') ?>
```

and it worked